# Why do I have an incorrect result set when I pass a String parameter?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I've debating with this problem for a while and I couldn't yet find a solution. It's very simple to explain.

I've a Java method that passes a String as parameter, and this String is a SQL Query.

When I execute this query passing the String parameter I get a result of 1 row.

> ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sqlq);

When I type the exact same query in the code i get the correct return of 5 rows.

> ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a.GSM_NO AS
>   A_GSM_NO,a.START_DATE AS A_START_DATE,a.INVOICE_DETAIL_CODE AS
>   A_INVOICE_DETAIL_CODE,a.VALUE_VAT_EXCLUDED AS A_VALUE_VAT_EXCLUDED,
>   b.GSM_NO AS B_GSM_NO,b.START_DATE AS
>   B_START_DATE,b.INVOICE_DETAIL_CODE AS
>   B_INVOICE_DETAIL_CODE,b.VALUE_VAT_EXCLUDED AS B_VALUE_VAT_EXCLUDED
>   FROM INVOICEPRINT_DETAIL_LEGACY a, INVOICEPRINT_DETAIL_GENESIS b WHERE
>   a.GSM_NO=b.GSM_NO AND a.START_DATE=b.START_DATE AND
>   a.INVOICE_DETAIL_CODE=b.INVOICE_DETAIL_CODE AND a.INVOICE_DETAIL_CODE
>   IN ( 'DT-ASUTOP' , 'DT-AVMAH4' , 'DT-BAGTOP' , 'DT-BNDTOP' ,
>   'DT-DIGTOP' , 'DT-FATTUT ' , 'DT-GORGPRF' )");

Yes, I printed the String Parameter and the content is exactly the same, although the output is diferent.

I made some tests and when the last part of the string has only:

> IN ( 'DT-ASUTOP' , 'DT-AVMAH4' , 'DT-BAGTOP' , 'DT-BNDTOP' ,
>
> > 'DT-DIGTOP')");

It works correctly passing the parameter or typing the Query manually. In this case it returns 4 rows, because in the field INVOICE_DETAIL_CODE 4 lines with DT-DIGTOP are found. Perfect and correct.

When I add DT-GORGPRF which is another value I'm looking for in the Column INVOICE_DETAIL_CODE, and it exists but only in one line, the result of the query with:

> IN ( 'DT-ASUTOP' , 'DT-AVMAH4' , 'DT-BAGTOP' , 'DT-BNDTOP' ,
>   'DT-DIGTOP' , 'DT-FATTUT ' , 'DT-GORGPRF' )");

when I pass the String Parameter returns only 1 row, the row with DT-GORGPRF  and ignores the last 4 rows. When I type the query manually to the executeQuery method i get the correct result.

This makes no sense. Can I get an input about how to workaround it?

Comment: My guess is that you are only reading the first row when you run it in java.

Comment: No, my code prints all the values in the ResultSet.. when i pass the query through  the parameter it prints 1 row.. when I pass the query typing it directly it prints 5 rows as it should...

Comment: fwiw - you may have a stray space after DT-FATTUT.

Comment: I removed all the spaces on the method that constructs the Query String and the result is exactly the same. =/

Comment: START_DATE is a keyword...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @xwpedram but if the problem was START_DATE it wouldnt work for the first query I make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after quite some days in top of this issue we found out that the dynamic query we were building through a StringBuilder had some invalid characters that caused this. To workaround we converted the Query to Ascii characters and remove all 13 (/n) that existed in ascii and shouldnt be there. We noticed that in some cases when using comas (,) the StringBuilder was adding /n characters that caused this awkard behaviour..!! Solved.

Answer (score -1):

In java code Remove ( ' ) and test .

```
IN ( DT-ASUTOP , DT-AVMAH4 , DT-BAGTOP , DT-BNDTOP , DT-DIGTOP , DT-FATTUT , DT-GORGPRF )");
```

Comment: Doesn't work, if I remove the (') SQL assumes - is a subtraction signal. I'm trying with (\') now